# Linux offline installation

Tags: system-installation, yum, rpm

I am working on building a Linux server offline with no internet connection. However, every time I try to install an app RH wants to check online for items and fails the installation. How do you configure so yum or rpm only look for local repos and bin Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/using-your-dvd-as-a-yum-repository-on-a-rpm-based-linux/ "Using your DVD as a yum repository on a RPM based Linux"

In a nutshell, edit repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d to point at the DVD, baseurl=file://media/Server

Comment: I tried that and now get a error repodata/repomd.xml.src cannot be opened.

Comment: @user148685 Suggest you update question to show the contents of your repo file and the command+error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the baseurl gpg to point to local locations such as this.

[media]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Server DVD Media
baseurl=file:///run/media/user/RHEL-7.2\ Server.x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-Key-redhat-release